# dlopen based application runs differently (erroneous) in the second time

Tags: c++, c, dlopen

I have an script interpreter that is spawn by a deamon and has to be up all the time.
In other words, as soon as it goes down (crash, segfault, normal termination, whatever), the daemon spawns that again.

This interpreter opens a library dynamically using `dlopen` (`lib1`).
This library opens a lot of other libraries (`lib2`, `lib3`, ...). Some of them make reference to the first library. So I'm using the `RTLD_GLOBAL` and `RTLD_NOW` flags for the `dlopen` call.

Up to this point, everything works well.

Problems arises when the interpreter is killed or crash and get spawned again.
I use dlopen once again, no problem... I can call `lib1`'s functions normally.
In `lib1`'s code, I make a call to a function from `lib2`.
The program just stops there.

It looks like it hasn't crashed (no segfault or something).
There is a debug call right before the call and other in the first line of the function.
The first gets executed. The second one doesn't.

One last detail: `lib1` is actually a C++ library that returns an object instance.
I'm omitting destroyer method from `lib1` and all the headers from all modules.
If anyone judge that important, I can give more information.

Does anyone have any idea on what may be happening?

To ilustrate scenario, consider the "pseudo" code:

Interpreter:

```
Lib1_obj *instance;

void interpreter_start() {
  // dlopen lib1
  // get lib1_creator symbol.
  instance = lib1_creator();
}

void interpreter_on_event_X() {
  int x = instance->method1();
  printf("x = %d\n", x);
}
```

Lib1:

```
class Lib1_obj {
public:
  int method1() {
    printf("Check point 1.\n");
    return lib2_do_something();
  }
}

Lib1_obj * creator() {
  return new Lib1_obj();
}
```

Lib2:

```
lib2_do_something() {
  printf("Check point 2.\n");
  return 1;
}
```

I suspect the problem has something to do with the fact I can't call `dlclose` when the process gets killed. Is it possible that it messes up the dlopen mechanism?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Is the _process_ killed or just some representation of a session within a process?

Comment: If your process is killed, the library will be automatically dlclose'd. As to the problem though -- while you've decided to concentrate on the problem with starting properly the second time, I personally would instead concentrate on not crashing in the first place.

Comment: That's the problem. Not crashing that.
It uses directfb. And I can't finilize directfb correctly. I'm not working in this modules, but the only way we are able to close that correctly is killing the process.
Even though, killing the process may cause different behaviour the second time we run it?

Comment: Sarnold, the process is killed (signal 9 - SIGKILL).

Comment: Are you sure all the libs being dynamically loaded have been compiled with -fPIC or whatever is equivalent for you compiler?

Comment: I'll double check that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Looks like that was the problem.
There was one module from another team that wasn't been compiled with -fPIC. I'm still testing, but it seems to do the trick.
Thanks very much user315052. If you want, post an answer to my question and I'll give up a +1.

Comment: @Marcus: Sorry, I didn't see this. if you don't do the `@` thing, your replies don't show up in the inbox of the person you are addressing in your question. But, I'm glad you were able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a lib that wasn't compiled with the -fPIC option.
Doing so solved the problem.

Thanks user315052 for the help.